# what is the fastest way to exclude the elements of a list from another lis in python?

Tags: python

I have large 2 lists and I want to exclude the elements of one from another.

Would it be faster to do plain

```
[x for x in list1 if x not in list2]
```

or should I transform list1 and/or list2 in another format (`set`, `dictionary` with key type = None, `hashMap`) or maybe use some preexising package function?
Thanks.

**EDIT:**
The order does not matter.

Comment: Define fastest.  Fastest to type?  To execute?  With what inputs?

Comment: @roippi : fastest to execute. Elements are strings of lengths from 10 to 50; there are about 1E4 elements in list2 and maybe 2E5 elements in list1. Naive [x for x in list1 if x not in list2]  takes ages.

Comment: Can you use sets or does list1 have repeated values?

Comment: @Christopher Harris : In my particular example it should not, but if it does, I am not intending to chase them

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is your slow method:

```
[x for x in list1 if x not in list2] #O(n*m)
```

Here is an EVEN SLOWER method:

```
[x for x in list1 if x not in set(list2)] #O(n*m) with extra overhead
```

Here is a fast method:

```
s = set(list2) #O(m)
[x for x in list1 if x not in s] #O(n)
```

`x in list2` is an O(n) operation.  x in `set(list2)` is O(1) for the `in` part, but O(n) for the set-building part.  The reason the second method is even slower is that it builds a new `set` for each membership test, instead of building it just once and doing lookups against that.

Comment: While certainly the fastest, I don't know I would characterize it as fast. The time to build the set and then iterate over the list could also be "ages" as the OP described. Just maybe not as many "ages." Worth a shot though before considering more elaborate solutions.

Comment: It is not ALWAYS true that `[x for x in list1 if x not in set(list2)]` will build the set every time. On Python 3.2+ the `set(list2)` part inside the comprehension is recognized as a closure and only built once.

Comment: @Vidya: 2e5 is very small for this kind of O(N) operation. This suggestion took only ~21 ms to apply on a dataset shaped like the OP's.

Comment: @DSM: That's good news. Were you able to run your test on data comparable to the OP's data? If it is just numbers or something primitive, that's cool. But more complex objects where you need to run `__eq__` every time might be slow. Just guessing of course.

Comment: @Vidya: comments in the post say they're strings of relatively small size.  @dawg: do you have a reference for that?  I'd have thought that was unlikely for several reasons, and `timeit` tests in Python 3.3 suggest otherwise, but I could easily have made a mistake.

Comment: I just tested it in python3.3 as well, the `in set(list2)` was very slow, as predicted.  If there is actually a version of python that would treat that as a closure that would be cool, so if there is, let me know.

Comment: @roippi: I tested it and I agree with you -- slow. However, tantalizing clues if you use `dis` on the function with `[x for x in list1 if x not in set(list2)]` in it. It is radically different that the same code in 2.7

Answer (score 1):

Others have beaten me to the Python in-memory solution, but I was going to add that seems to be a case of treating the symptom rather than curing the disease. Why are there lists that big in memory in the first place?

Obviously I have no idea about the nature of the application, but consider alternatives like using a database, running background batch jobs and caching results, etc. to try to solve this issue with a better design.

Comment: You are right, in the ideal world this should belong to the database code. But I need to finish something today, so I do not have time to migrate all my stuff in SQL...

Comment: Got it. We've all been there. In that case, I think @roippi's solution is your best chance.

Answer (score 1):

If you can use sets and items are not repeated:

```
a = set(list1)
b = set(list2)

c = a.difference(b)
```

Comment: What if `list1` has desired duplicates?

Answer (score 1):

I would go with the set solution, a quick micro-benchmark in the console might look like this (personally I wouldn't worry about the set construction overhead, unless often executed):

```
list1 = range(50000)
list2 = range(10000, 20000)

%timeit [x for x in list1 if x not in list2]
# 8.48 s per loop


slist2 = set(list2)

%timeit [x for x in list1 if x not in slist2]
# 3.62 ms per loop
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's an approach that destroys the original order, but may well be faster, "depending".  It relies on the little-known `elements()` method of `collections.Counter` objects:

```
from collections import Counter

xs = ["abc", "def", "abc", "abc", "def", "def", "xyz"]
ys = ["def", "def", "jik"]

xsc = Counter(xs)
for y in set(ys):  # if y has few repeated elements, skip `set()`
    xsc[y] = 0
print list(xsc.elements())
```

which prints (maybe - the order isn't defined!):

```
['xyz', 'abc', 'abc', 'abc']
```

Answer (score 0):

The only thing to speed up is the test for membership in `list2`, so try

```
[ x for x in list1 if x not in set(list2) ]
```

Whether or not this is faster depends on whether time saved by doing `len(list1)` operations on the set makes up for the time it takes to build the set, which depends on the lengths of both lists.